# Where to learn axiomatic geometry from Hilbert's axioms?

Tags: textbooks

I have found that math is relative easy for me to study but I have problems in geometry. I often omit some obvious steps as I think the problem visually but not from axioms. What would help me for that problem? Are there good books to learn geometry from Hilbert's axioms to, say, IMO level problems and shows how to add a measure theory to geometry such that one can measure lengths, angles and areas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclidean and Non-euclidean Geometry by Greenberg is my pick, although it doesn't prove the measure results you want. (However, it does have references)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking at *Geometry, Euclid and Beyond* by Robin Hartshorne.

From the preface: *The course begins in Chapter 1 with a critical examination of Euclid's Elements. Students are expected to read concurrently Books I-IV of Euclid's text, which must be obtained sepa­rately. The remainder of the book is an exploration of questions that arise natu­rally from this reading, together with their modern answers. To shore up the foundations we use Hilbert's axioms.*

Comment: This and Greenberg were the only two books that came to mind but I haven't looked at either in detail. I actually have this one and I can tell that it's a fantastic book. I happen to get incredibly bored and unmotivated by an axiomatic slog through geometry though, so I've never made much of a dent in it. For the later chapters I remember the reader is expected to know algebra up to Galois theory.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to learn geometry from Hilbert's axioms is his own book Foundations of Geometry.

However I don't see any reasons to learn Geometry "from Hilbert axioms". There are quite a few really good modern textbooks on geometry, my favorite one is Hartshorne (recommended in the answer of user52817), which covers more of less the contents of Euclid but from modern point of view.

Another good elementary geometry book (which covers much more, and not tied to Euclid) is M. Berger, Geometry.